# UEFI pre-boot environment exception when booting with custom-built Linux kernel

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, uefi, bios

I'm trying to build Linux kernel from scratch.
My current system with an Intel Xeon Gold 6242 CPU, running Linux 5.4.0-050400-generic kernel on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
The steps I have followed to build the kernel are as follows:

1. `cd /path/to/new/kernel/source` (the source hasn't been modified after download)
2. `cp -v /boot/config-5.4.0-050400-generic ./.config`
3. `make menuconfig`, load and save the copied `.config file` (the `.config` contents don't really change but the order of lines do change)
4. `make -j32`
5. `make modules_install install`
   Everything runs fine with no errors until I eventually do reboot and when I choose the new kernel to boot with, it fails with the following message:
   [image]

Here are some other options I have tried to get it to work:

1. Build Linux 5.18.0 from source (because Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS uses Linux 5.4 as its main kernel so I thought maybe versions from the past might not work): **fails with the same error message**
2. Instead of copying the `.config` file that is already in use, just **make a new `.config` file** with `make menuconfig` and not loading/saving from an existing `.config` file: **fails with the same error message**
3. Instead of building kernels from source, try to install a new kernel directly from the Ubuntu mainline kernels: **works fine (Linux 5.15.0)**

I have checked out some similar questions like [Compiling the Linux kernel and booting with UEFI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626398/), [not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414655/), and [Unable to boot using self built kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93594/) but haven't had any luck.
One last thing: this is a [duplicate question from Reddit I posted a few days ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/kernel/comments/wt6dq1/), but am reposting here because unfortunately I haven't received much help there.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same exact issue on the R640. The fix I made was to do a `make -j "$(nproc)" bindeb-pkg` after running `make`, and then installing the `.deb` packages via `dpkg` rather than running `make modules_install install`

Who knows what the actual root cause of the issue is.